# Analytic sheaves for Cartan's theorem

Tags: complex-geometry, coherent-sheaves

When reading about Cartan's theorems for Stein manifolds (theorems A & B), about half of the sources state this in terms of coherent sheaves and half of them uses coherent "analytic" sheaves. I was wondering why some sources deem it necessary to introduce the adjective "analytic"?

As far as I know all complex manifolds are complex analytic spaces and, hence, the coherent sheaves associated to their structure sheaves are automatically analytic.

Comment: I would guess it's to make the distinction between the analytic topology, and the Zariski topology on an algebraic variety.

Comment: But would there be any chance of confusing these two in case of complex manifolds?

Comment: Affine algebraic curves could be seen as compact Riemann surfaces with finitely many points removed. These would be considered as algebraic curves with the Zariski topology, by algebraic geometers. Meanwhile, they are also Stein manifolds. So I imagine that it's worthwhile to notice the distinction.

Comment: That is a nice example indeed. Thanks!